# dominant versus dominierend

Tags: meaning-in-context, participle

Im Kurztext zu einem Artikel auf [tagesschau.de](https://tagesschau.de) heißt es am 22.12.21:

> Um Weihnachten - so schätzen Experten - wird Omikron auch in Deutschland die dominante Variante sein.

[image: screenshot tagesschau.de]
<sub>Leider kommt diese Formulierung nur im Kurztext vor. Im eigentlichen Artikel heißt es dann *vorherrschend*. Deshalb die Abbildung.</sub>

Nun zu meiner Frage:

Müsste es nicht heißen:

> ... wird die **dominierende** Variante sein

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dominant) setzt die Bedeutungen gleich:

> dominant Adj. ‘vorherrschend’ (18. Jh.), lat. domināns (Genitiv dominantis), Part. Präs. zu dominārī; heute meist dominierend.

Auch [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dominant) unterscheidet die Bedeutungen nicht und erklärt *dominant* mit *dominierend*.

Allerdings ist - soweit man die gängigen Wortarten zugrunde legt -

- dominant ein Adjektiv
- dominierend Partizip I zum Verb *dominieren*

Es scheint mir daher doch einen Unterschied zu geben. Während *dominant* der Omikronvariante eine allgemeine Eigenschaft zuschreibt, ist im Artikel die Rede von einem zu einem bestimmten Zeitpunkt zu beobachtenden Verhältnis gegenüber anderen Varianten.

Ein grundsätzlich dominanter Gesprächspartner muss z.B. ein Gespräch nicht unbedingt dominieren.

Gibt es diesen Unterschied oder liege ich damit falsch und man kann tatsächlich sagen, dass *dominant* nur heute meist durch *dominierend* ersetzt wird?

Comment: Die Bedeutung nach DWDS ist "vorherrschend"; Sie zitieren die Etymologie. Das englische Wort "prevail" ist auch mehrdeutig, und in gleicher Weise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im Prinzip bedeuten beide Wörter genau dasselbe und haben auch dieselbe Herkunft.

*dominant* ist eine lateinische (wurde also bereits als Partizip eingedeutscht), *dominierend* eine deutsche Partizipbildung (hier wurde wohl das Verb *dominari* eingedeutscht und dann erst im Deutschen das Partizip Präsens dazu gebildet).

Ein kleiner Unterschied ergibt sich *vermeintlich* aus dem Sprachgebrauch, wo (ausserhalb der Vererbungslehre) *dominant* mehr für Persönlichkeiten und Charaktere (also die Eigenschaft), *dominierend* eher für andere Dinge (also die Tätigkeit) gebraucht zu werden scheint. Ein tatsächlicher Unterschied besteht aber nicht.

Der von dir vermutete Bedeutungsunterschied kommt eher von einer grundsätzlichen Mehrdeutigkeit des Partizip Präsens (sowohl im Deutschen als auch im Lateinischen) her, die nicht unbedingt zwischen einer momentanen Tätigkeit (er dominiert = ist grade dominant) und einer grundsätzlichen Eigenschaft (er dominiert *immer* = ist grundsätzlich dominant) unterscheiden kann.

Comment: Ah, ok. Vielen Dank! Ich hatte gehofft, dass jemand mit sattelfesten Lateinkenntnissen hier Licht ins Dunkel bringen kann. Sehr interessant! Danke!